# how to call AsyncTask sequentially

Tags: android, if-statement, android-asynctask, controls

I have 4 AsyncTask that update my db from the server, but i have a considerable data on each one, so i wanna start each Asynctask after the end of the last one,

by the click of a button, i tried with a "IF" but i didn't get success so i'm posting my code here to let you guys help me in that...

"i just tried to do that, but eclipse didn't compile this code because is wrong, so because my knowledge limitation i thought, in something like that any soluitons ??"

```
atualiza_base = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_button);
    atualiza_base.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            new callServiceCliente().execute();
            if (calServiceCliente().getStatus == FINISHED) {
                new callServiceMaterial().execute();
            }else if (callServiceMaterial().getStatus == FINISHED) {
                new callServiceProblema().execute();
            }else if (callServiceProblema().getStatus == FINISHED) {
                new callServiceProcedencia().execute();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Database Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

thanks a lot...

Comment: asked many times ... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html guess what `this` means inside it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Onclick of button start first `AsyncTask` and then in **onPostExecute()** method of each `AsyncTask` (except last `AsyncTask`) execute next `AsyncTask`. This will solve your problem.

Make sure you handled your exceptions in **doInBackground()** method to get call to **onPostExecute()**.

Answer (score 2):

In each AsyncTask class, call the next AsyncTask in the `onPostExecute` method.